# How to use reverse routing with scalatags in playframework?

Tags: playframework, templating, scalatags

While using twirl, it's straightforward, we use `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")">` and the served html files contain appropriately resolved links.

In the case of using scalatags templating with playFW, how do we achieve the same thing? Doing `link(rel:="stylesheet", media:="screen", href:=routes.Assets.versioned("lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"))`

build.sbt has `"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "4.1.3"`. IJ complains:

> No implicit argument of type: AttrValue[Builder_,Call]

rendered webpage complains

> No AttrValue defined for type play.api.mvc.Call; scalatags does not know how to use play.api.mvc.Call as an attribute